# Grub and Renaming... Why does Kubuntu 9.10 make it so hard?

Tags: terminal, grub

I'm trying to rearrange the grub menu in Kubuntu 9.10 (similar to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/82143/change-the-boot-menu-grub)), but unfortunately, Kubuntu includes the latest (and NOT greatest) version of grub, which no longer uses the elegant menu.lst.  ARG!  So anyway, I'm digging around in /etc/grub.d and I can't figure out how to rename the files in order to get them to boot in another order.

> (on a side note, I can't get xPUD to show up in the boot list... but that is a little less important)

So why doesn't it work to do `sudo grub` in the terminal?  (that seems to be the easiest option, but that doesn't work either.)

Further, why can't I rename the files?

- Do I need to do it in the terminal?  If so, how do I rename the file with the terminal?
- Can I run Dolphin (or Konqueror or whatever) as root (or su)?
- And don't tell me I need to try CHMOD first; I already tried that, and I still couldn't rename the file.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: [Grub 2 ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275), this should get you going.  Grub 2 is new and different but once you get used to it I like it better.

You do not edit a file like menu.lst.

Answer (score 0):

What *exactly* happens if you try to do something like

```
cd /etc/grub.d
sudo mv 20_memtest86+ 90_memtest86+
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed (at least as far as renaming goes). 

Does anyone have any idea how to add xPUD to the list?

Comment: @NH: All you have to do is put a few lines in the `_custom` file.