# Make grub keep its default boot under kernel updates

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, kernel

I dual-boot my machine and I want it to default to boot into windows so that whenever I restart the machine remotely from my home it will be able to get back into Windows (instead of Ubuntu).

The problem is that every time Ubuntu upgrades the kernel, I have to reset the default boot item of grub back to windows. This is because the grub menu loader uses positions i.e. 6 for default OS to boot. And when Ubuntu installs a new kernel it changes that order.

I am looking for a way to configure grub to remember its default boot item under kernel updates.

Answer (score 9):

### Grub 1 (Ubuntu 9.04 and earlier)

I find the easiest way to do this is to move the Windows boot entry above the Ubuntu entries in `/boot/grub/menu.lst`.  By default, the Grub configuration file is laid out like this:

1. basic options
2. debian auto-magic kernel config (including utilities like memtest86+ by default)
3. other detected OS's

Section 2 is demarcated by these lines in the config file:

```
### BEGIN AUTOMAGIC KERNELS LIST
(lots of stuff here)
### END DEBIAN AUTOMAGIC KERNELS LIST
```

Entries for autodetected OS's (eg, Windows) are placed after this section.  When you install a new kernel, section 2 is the only section that gets changed.  So moving the autodetected OS to somewhere *before* the `BEGIN` line will place it where the entry number won't change when a new kernel gets installed.

---

### Grub 2 (Ubuntu 9.10 and later)

With Grub2, the entire configuration file is created anew anytime `update-grub` is run, so editing `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` won't be a permament fix.  How that file is generated is handled by the files `/etc/default/grub` and the scripts in `/etc/grub.d/*`. So we modify the configuration by modifing the files which control individual sections of the configfile, then running `update-grub` again.

My `/etc/grub.d` includes these files:

- 00_header
- 05_debian_theme
- 10_hurd
- 10_linux
- 20_memtest86+
- 21_memtest86
- 30_os-prober
- 40_custom

These are shellscripts that get run *in order* to generate the config file.  The Windows boot entry is generated by `30_os-prober`, which is run *after* the linux boot entries are generated in `10_linux`.  So just rename `30_os-prober` to something less than 10, and rerun `update-grub`

```
mv /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober /etc/grub.d/09_os-prober
update-grub
```

Now your Windows entry should be the first entry, and you can set that as the default boot entry (`GRUB_DEFAULT=`) in `/etc/default/grub`.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the instructions on my blog [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CBYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fright-now-in-tech.blogspot.com%2F2010%2F08%2Fuse-windows-bootloader-to-boot-windows.html&ei=uvd0TKUww6txxfTN3gU&usg=AFQjCNHSiAxkXaB0lJEhFt43atVDIL1SZw&sig2=qjhEpxg6EQYwYdamnc81MA) to use the clean Windows bootloader for your job. I use it now, and when I start the PC, I have two options:

Windows Vista
Ubuntu 10.04

There is no other clutter. You can set many different options for it too. If I do not press anything for 5 seconds, Windows boots up.

Good luck.

Comment: that link is nearly dead