# Buildroot Kernel building with CONFIG_EFI_STUB=y for systemd-boot (gummiboot)

Tags: linux, kernel, systemd

systemd-boot (Previosuly, gummiboot) requires linux kernel to be built as EFISTUB
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot
However, I don't see any option in Buildroot config to build kernel as EFISTUB.
What is Buildroot option to set kernel building with CONFIG_EFI_STUB=y

Minimal Linux Live does that way.
https://github.com/ivandavidov/minimal/blob/master/src/02_build_kernel.sh#L81

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586673/how-to-create-uefi-bootable-image-from-bzimage-custom-kernal answers this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make grub keep its default boot under kernel updates](https://superuser.com/questions/102692/make-grub-keep-its-default-boot-under-kernel-updates)